# Dynamic update Label with response from RestAPI like ajax in tkinter

Tags: ajax, rest, tkinter

I am writing a tkinter app, which will be client for Web Application . I need a Label field, which need to dynamically updated from the response from a Rest API provided by the Web Application.

The Rest API call should be asynchronous and it should be continously polling the RESTAPI and when ever the value changes, the Label Value should change. (Like Ajax call in Web Application)

I have some other buttton and all in tha app.

I am able to find a solution for the same. Request to provide a solution. I am stuck in the development because of the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use
`label.config(text="desired text from response")` from inside a function which polls the desired endpoint and extracts the appropriate text. The call will need to be in a function kicked off in a thread to not block the GUI.